# c# Delegate Class Return value is empty

Tags: c#, delegates

i have the following code, but the problem is that when i exucte it without using the delegate thread it goes smooth but when i use the delegate then it give me the erro:

> NullReferenceException Was Unhandled, Object Reference not set to an instance of an object/

the code is:

```
 public static string  makezip_thread(string [] files,bool IsOriginal) 

   {

        string paths="";
        Thread starter = new Thread (delegate(){ paths = Makezipfile(files,IsOriginal);});
        starter.IsBackground = true;
        starter.Start();

        return paths;
    }
```

my zip Making Class:

```
public static string Makezipfile(string[] files, bool IsOriginal)
    {

        string[] filenames = new string[files.Length];
        if (IsOriginal)
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                filenames[i] = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Remove(0,10).ToString();
        else
            for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
                filenames[i] = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + files[i].Replace(HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString(), "");
        string DirectoryName = filenames[0].Remove( filenames[0].LastIndexOf('/') );
           DirectoryName = DirectoryName.Substring(DirectoryName.LastIndexOf('/') + 1).Replace("\\","");

        try
        {

           string newFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.PhysicalApplicationPath + "images\\Thumbnails\\zipFiles\\" + DirectoryName + ".zip";
            if(File.Exists(newFile))
                File.Delete(newFile);
            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {

                foreach (string file in filenames)
                {

                    string newfileName = file.Replace("\\'", "'");
                    zip.CompressionLevel=0;
                    zip.AddFile(newfileName, "");
                }

                zip.Save(newFile);
            }
 return a;
```

}

Comment: There isnt enough information here to answer the question properly.  Are you saying that if you just execute Makezipfile(...) without the thread, you get your expected result?

Comment: @ Chris, Shain: yes exactly, if i call the method without using the thread, it goes ok, but when i use it in the thread, it reaturn the above mention error :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to do exactly what you want, in any case.

By trying to push this into a separate thread, chances are you'll (probably always) return `string.Empty` as a result of this method.

The reason for this is that your `return paths;` line will return far before `Makezipfile` can execute successfully.

If you want this to be an asynchronous method, you need to rework it to be an asynchronous method.  There are many options, including the [APM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228963.aspx) and the [EAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wewwczdw.aspx) models for asynchrony in .NET 3.5 and earlier.  In .NET 4, the best option here would be to turn this into a method that returns `Task<string>`:

```
public static Task<string> MakeZipAsync(string [] files,bool IsOriginal) 
{
    return Task.Factory.StartNew( () =>
       {
           return Makezipfile(files, IsOriginal);
       });
}
```

You'd then use this like:

```
var zipTask = MakeZipAsync(files, true);
// Do other work...

// Later, when you need the results, you can block and retrieve them:
var paths = zipTask.Result;
```

Comment: @ Reed Copsey: What is the best in this case either APM or EAP more easy to implement and less Buggie :) thansk

Comment: @safi: If you're using .NET 4, use `Task<string>`.  In .NET <=3.5, EAP is easier to develop in most cases.

Comment: @ Reed Copsey: I have added my Zip method with the code also, you can see that, can you give me some more clue :)

Comment: @safi: You need to pull out the HttpContext routines, and pass them into your method.  You can't use HttpContext inside the background thread (safely).